# CORS Error - Ajax request returns intermittent failures with NYTimes API

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, asp.net-web-api

I am making several ajax requests to the [NYTimes Congress API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/congress_api#h3-current-member), whilst iterating over an array of districts (1 to 5).  I am only able to successfully return 2 requests on average, the rest returning a:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/congress/members/house/OR/2/current.json?api-key=xxxxxxx.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9001' is therefore not allowed access.`

It appears that there is no pattern to these failings. Even using the same `_district` number multiple times fails seemingly randomly.

My code:

```
var title_element,
    title_render,
    district_numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    element_ids = ['ushd1', 'ushd2', 'ushd3', 'ushd4', 'ushd5'],
    apiKey = 'api-key=xxxxxxxxxxx',
    baseUrl = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/congress/members/house/OR/',
    orUsHouseMembers,
    frag;

  for (var i = 0, total_districts = district_numbers.length; i < total_districts; i++) {
      (function (i) {
        var myUrl = baseUrl + district_numbers[i] + '/current.json?' + apiKey;

        $.ajax({
          url: myUrl,
          dataType: 'json',

          success: function (data) {
            console.log('\nSUCCESS: ' + myUrl);
            title_element = document.getElementById(element_ids[i]);        
            title_render = document.createTextNode(data.results[0].name + ' - District ' + data.results[0].district );
            title_element.appendChild(title_render);
          },

          error: function (data) {
            console.log('\nFAIL: ' + myUrl);
          }
        })
      })(i);
  }
```

I tried adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` and all the usual CORS stuff, but I dont expect this to be a true CORS issue as the failures are too intermittent

Is something in my code amiss or maybe the API?

Answer (score 1):

> Is something in my code amiss or maybe the API?

Yes, instead of `json`, change the AJAX's `dataType` option to `jsonp`:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

In order to avoid of [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues when you ***only*** want to `GET` data, use [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584/952310).

---

**P.S:**

Note that I tested it by myself in a small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/pptt2/) that I made using jsFiddle and it's working correctly, just ***take on account*** that it's now returns `403 (Forbidden)` - I assume because I should enter a valid `api-key`, you provided a fake one (`api-key=xxxxxxxxxxx`).

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately, even with JSONP (and inserting my api key) it is only returning two results:
`Suzanne Bonamici - District 1 
Greg Walden - District 2 
Error 
Error 
Error `

Comment: @elthatcher Well, first, now you managed to established a successful communication with the API server, second, the problem now is with the data which you're trying to fetch from the API - It's seems like there is no such data per your query.

Comment: The data seems to exist when queried with [3,4,5,4,5] yielding: `Earl Blumenauer - District 3 
Peter A. DeFazio - District 4 
Kurt Schrader - District 5 
Error 
Error `

Comment: Unfortunately I need no errors - i.e. five returned `'data.results[0].name + ' - District ' + data.results[0].district'` combinations to consider the problem solved.  There are still random failures and only two requests returned instead of five.