# Connecting New York Times API JSON data to display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, each

I'm working on the API project now in javascript, and I have not been able to find any answers for how to place the json data from the New York Times API into my html. I have successfully linked to [the NYT API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2#examples).

In the js below, the `findSearch()` function successfully gets the data from the NY site, but when I use the `$.each()` to call to the `showData(i, result)` function, the data comes back as undefined.

I can see that the data is making it’s way up to this function because of a `console.log()` I did in the `showData()` function, but I think I am calling the json data incorrectly.

To see the entire project (it’s not the big; don't worry), you [can go here](http://keithand.github.io/mad_libs/).

```
var showData = function (i, result) {

var template = $(".results .template .searchDisplay").clone();

var headline = template.find('.headline');
headline.text(result.response.docs.headline);

var abstract = template.find('.abstract');
abstract.text(result.response.docs.abstract);

var snippet = template.find('.snippet');
snippet.text(result.response.docs.snippet); 

var url = template.find('.url');
url.text(result.response.docs.url);

console.log(result)
console.log(result.response.docs.headline)

$('.searchDisplay').show('fast');

return result;
};


// THIS FUNCTION CALLS OUT TO THE NYT API, GETS DATA
var findSearch = function(search){

var request =   {tagged: search,
                site: 'New York Times',
                order: 'decs',
                sort: 'creation'};

var result = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=' + search + '&fq=source:("The New York Times")&page=0&sort=oldest&api-key=a1eeb62c8df499298c449983e6967154:3:69423736',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: search,
})
.done(function(result) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(result.response);
    var searchResults = showSearchData(request.tagged, result.response.docs.length );
    $('.info').html(searchResults);

    $.each(result.response.docs, function(i, item) {
        var showing = showData(item, result);
        $('.searchDisplay').append(showing);
    });
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
    $('.results').html('This feature is not working. :-(');
});
```

Comment: I think that this link might be helpful: [CORS Error - Ajax request returns intermittent failures with NYTimes API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23861852/952310)

Comment: Thanks, @YairNevet. I will look look more into this to see if this is the same issue.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I called out the elements in the json incorrectly. Sorry for posting this!

Comment: Please create an answer so others can learn from the mistake, or delete this question.